# Looking for a permanent non-battery solution to starting car

Tags: batteries, motor, automotive

I own a diesel car and live in Minnesota, where it gets quite cold in the winter, and more than a dozen times a year, my car will not start.  I've tried many often-suggested solutions.  I've bought new car batteries, both cheap and expensive.  None has lasted more than 18 months before failing to start the car.  Some lasted as little as 6 months.  I've installed a charger in the car and plug it in overnight.  This works maybe 1/3 of the time, but the rest of the time, the car still fails to start.  I've tried to find a block-heater that can be used to warm up the engine so it starts more easily, but have been unable to find one compatible with my model of car.  I've investigated getting a remote-start package installed that can be set to start the car periodically throughout the night to keep the engine and the battery warm, but I'm told no one will install such a thing because it would have to bypass the car's security system, and they're all afraid of getting sued if someone breaks into my car.  I've bought a "car-start" quick charger that is supposed to charge up the battery quickly to allow me to start the car even when it's depleted, but after a couple years it has become convinced that all batteries (even dead ones) are fully charged and refuses to do anything other than float-charge them.  I've tried purchasing a jump-pack.  That lasted a couple years but then the battery in it died as well.  I've tried hooking up an extra battery to the car when starting it.  This works, but it also kills the extra battery within a year.  It appears my car and the climate here simply eat batteries.  Even batteries that aren't IN the car.  If they're used to start it, they die, and absurdly quickly.  I really want a non-battery solution to this problem, even if it's  many hundreds of dollars.  At the rate I'm going through batteries and chargers it wouldn't take long to pay for itself.  I was hoping for something that I could simply plug into a socket in my garage that would provide the car with enough power to start.  But at this point I'd settle for a hand crank.  Or maybe someone here has a more novel solution?  Just please don't suggest anything involving batteries.  My front porch is filling up with batteries, and none of them work anymore.  My wife is getting worried they will begin to migrate into the house.  If I never have to deal with a car battery again, it will be too soon.

Comment: This might be a better fit at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why aren't you recycling your dead batteries? Also, I take it you don't keep your car in a garage overnight.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a question for an electrical engineer, this is a question for a mechanic.

Comment: I would discuss this problem with a local garage or car dealer.  Do others in your area have the same problems?  If not, what are you doing with your car that they are not?

Comment: How about a small heater and the battery together in a thermally isolated box and adding some percent gasoline to the diesel? That worked for my very old Mercedes.

Comment: You need a block heater.

Comment: I need to know the CCA Cold-Cranking-Amps your battery is rated for to verify my numbers.  If we lose touch, Supercapacitors should do it for you, but we have to find out how many and in what form. I started up my car twice with a pack I made, and it's supposed to operate down to -40 degrees C, which is what you desperately need. They should also last a long time. You probably also need Lithium-ion involved.

Comment: I live up a mountain in Switzerland and on the coldest nights in winter I put a little ceramic 300W heater under the hood. Comes on at 5AM ready for 7.30AM and starts like a summer day. 17 year old 2.2 litre diesel…

Comment: I presume you've tried using a calcium battery?

Comment: buy a battery heater

Comment: some people are using supercapacitors to start their cars.